# Import encrypted session key

Tags: encryption, cryptography, saml, cryptoapi

I have asn.1 structure (encrypted session key):

```
SEQUENCE(2 elem)
  SEQUENCE(2 elem)
    OCTET STRING(32 byte) 5E70735F3698B4355B45037FA7CE0097115E45C6585994726642063F723AB49E
    OCTET STRING(4 byte) 8C860884
  [0](3 elem)
    OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.643.2.2.31.1
    [0](2 elem)
      SEQUENCE(2 elem)
        OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.643.2.2.19
        SEQUENCE(2 elem)
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.643.2.2.36.0
          OBJECT IDENTIFIER1.2.643.2.2.30.1
      BIT STRING(1 elem)
        OCTET STRING(64 byte) 2DC3FDF69C913DCCB653268E512F5EDDE41A5DB3583CDF6068F248A2B0B8DE7BC9AA20E3CF63DF5F395521E0A0DD853E0AAF44FA493CD54CA8048D1D9C4185FB
    OCTET STRING(8 byte) 76EEB46B1B1036EB
```

How to decrypt this structure using the function CryptImportKey?

Answer (score 1):

That structure uses the Russian GOST protocols. I'm pretty certain that those are not supported by `CryptImportKey` out of the box. You probably have to extract the information and then import it using a structure that is supported by `CryptImportKey`.

For instance [OID 1.2.643.2.2.19 shows {iso(1) member-body(2) ru(643) 2 cryptopro(2) gostR3410-2001(19)}](http://www.oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.2.643.2.2.19&submit=Display&action=display).

It seems you could use some kind of plugin, probably you could obtain this from [CryptoPro](http://www.cryptopro.ru/). I'm not sure though, my Russian is not that good (and my friend Anya is not into crypto :) ).

Comment: I use Crypto.
Example my code http://pastebin.com/WHXhbXHx. The error occurs on line 194 (Error 0x80090005).
I think the problem is in the structure SIMPLEBLOB.

Comment: And somehow you didn't think that information should be included in the question?

Comment: @shushlyakov You may use OllyDbg to check your hypothesis: just set a breakpoint on CryptImportKey and, once it's hit, watch closely; it won't be quick, but eventually you will come across the instruction that throws the error. To narrow the initial search, you may also use *trace* mode instead of *step-into* / *step-over*, setting condition to EAX is equal 0x80090005.